# Can these data points be used to form a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

If I have the following data points: $(-7,-1)(-5,1)(-1,-3)(3,1)(6,-2)$

With the correct assumptions, is this enough information to derive a $4^{th}$ degree polynomial function?

Comment: He has 5 point on polynomial of 4. degree. @Paul

Comment: Exact one polynomial with degree $4$ or less passes the points, but the data need not fit with this polynomial anymore if we determine additional points. If we assume that a polynomial with degree at most $4$ is a suitable model, interpolation is the correct solution.

Comment: To actually decide which is the case, we need more context (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: @Peter in terms of context, this was largely curiosity, and my knowledge of calculus did not allow me easily google a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a unique way to define a polynomial function of degree $n-1$ given its values on $n$ points. See Lagrange interpolation, for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: What is the reason for the downvotes ?

Comment: Most certainly not unique.

Comment: @Peter it's incorrect as written. In particular, polynomials are not unique. I didn't downvote.

Comment: We have $5$ points, hence a unique polynomial (with degree $4$ or less) passing the points.

Comment: When you have more points, then it's no longer unique. I believe its been corrected now.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write "of degree $n-1$". Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Another question is whether a polynomial actually fits with the data, but we only have $5$ points , so nothing speaks against interpolating.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up with the following: $$ -(989 x^4)/120120 - (961 x^3)/40040 + (43139 x^2)/120120 + (24601 x)/40040 - 1579/572 $$